# I have button which are repeating so i want to change the color of button which i selected how do i do this

Tags: lightning-web-components

```html
<template for:each={FixtureData} for:item="item">
    <lightning-button style="padding:6px 12px;margin:0 0 
                                 [![enter image description here][1]][1]15px 0;display:inline-block;"
                      value={item.value}
                      key={item.value}
                      label={item.label}
                      data-value={item.value}
                      onclick={FixtureDataFn}
                      variant="neutral">
    </lightning-button>
</template>
```

JS

```js
this.FixtrueData=event.target.label; 
this.template.querySelector('lightning-button').variant='bra‌​nd';
```

[image]
See the image it is repeating like this 
So I want to do like if I select the Industrial button then it shows selected and the color of button should be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99544/discussion-between-rahul-gawale-and-areeb).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing this error

> If property variant decorated with @api in [object:vm undefined (2)]
>   is used in the template, the value bra‌​nd set manually may be
>   overridden by the template, consider binding the property only in the
>   template.

You cannot edit the standard lightning properties of the lightning button from JS directly.
You can achieve this using property. You need to bind the variant attribute to render the variant property of the button.

```
<template>
    <template for:each={FixtureData} for:item="item">
        <lightning-button style="padding:6px 12px;margin:0 0 5px 0;display:inline-block;" 
         label={item.label} 
         data-value={item.value} 
         onclick={FixtureDataFn} 
         variant={item.variant}
         key={item.index}
         data-index = {item.index}>
        </lightning-button>
    </template>
</template>
```

In the Js controller below, I have used a property `variant` with default value = `neutral`.
On the click of a button, I am changing this attribute value for each button from the JS controller method. Here I have used data property to locate the current button. Based on index the variant property is set to `brand`.

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    @track FixtureData = [{label: 'One', variant: 'neutral',index: 0},
     {index: 1, label: 'Two',variant: 'neutral'}, {index:2,label: 'Three',variant: 'neutral'}];

    FixtureDataFn(event){
        let index = parseInt(event.currentTarget.dataset.index);
        console.log(index);

        let newButtons = [...this.FixtureData];
        console.log('len ' + this.FixtureData.length);
        console.log('len ' + newButtons.length);
        for(let i=0; i<newButtons.length; i++){
            if(i === index){
                newButtons[i].variant = "brand";
            } else {
                newButtons[i].variant = "neutral";
            }
        }
        this.FixtureData = [...newButtons];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(newButtons[index]));
    }
}
```

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/HnGZuNxhk/1/edit) is the live example for it.